# Select dependientes en angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de hacer un `select` dependiente de países  que al momento de seleccionar un país se carguen los estados pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo en **Angular 2**

```
      <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="pais"> {{'etq.pais' | i18n}}</label>
                      <select id="pais" [(ngModel)]="lugar.idPais" name="idPais" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" disabled><{{'etq.seleccione' | i18n}}></option>
                        <option *ngFor="let pais of paisesArray" [value]="pais.id" >{{pais.descripcion}}</option>
                      </select>

                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Deberías dar más información...que haz intentado hasta ahora... un demo online quizás en [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/)? Además viendo tu historial de preguntas y cual ninguna de esas haz aceptado como correcta es decir que pones poco interés si se te soluciona o no... dudo que a este ritmo te ayude alguien... saludos

Comment: Es que no se realmente como usar bien esto, de que manera puedo indicar que con tal respuesta se soluciono mi problema?

Comment: fácil... hay un check `√` al lado del voto... lo clickeas y listo...siempre y cuando te solucione la pregunta claro

Comment: No vendría mal que empezaras a marcar las respuestas que te solucionan los problemas como resueltas. Ayudarás al resto de la comunidad.

Comment: Pudiste solucinarlo? Si es asi, me comentarias como?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que setear dos listas en tu `component.ts`, una para los paises ej: `let paises: Pais[]` y otra para los estados `let estados: Estado[]`

Luego le seteas a cada select que el dataprovider van a ser los recien creados EJ;

```
<select [(ngModel)]="paises">
   <option [ngValue]="pais" *ngFor="let pais of paises" (click)="handleChange(item)">{{label(item)}}</option>
</select>
```

Y

```
<select [(ngModel)]="estados">
  <option [ngValue]="estado" *ngFor="let estado of estados" (click)="handleChange(item)">{{label(item)}}</option>
</select>
```

Por ultimo en el método handleChange cambias la lista de estados según el país pasado por parametro, algo así como:

```
handleChange(pais) {
   this.estados = pais.estados;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `ngModelChange` para detectar los cambios de estado de tu modelo.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="lugar.idPais" (ngModelChange)="handlePaisChange($event.target.data)">
  <option value="" disabled><{{'etq.seleccione' | i18n}}></option>
  <option *ngFor="let pais of paisesArray" [value]="pais.id" >{{pais.descripcion}</option>
</select>

handlePaisChange(pais) {
  this.estados = // código para obtener estados con pais;
}
```

Fuente: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel